# RAM over http client agent?

Tags: http, smartcard, sim-card, globalplatform

I have a requirement to build a server that deploy applets into sim cards over the air using http as defined in globalplatform amd.B specs and ETSI TS 102225 and 102226.

My question is about the http client on the sim cards. Do SIM cards have the http agent embedded by manufacturer before issuing the cards or do I have to provide the http client applet as part of the solution?

Comment: OTA keys are specific per SIM card or they are specific per operator typically?

Comment: Each sim card has its own set of keys, typically two OTA keys one for encryption and the second for checksum calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can take it for granted. But your client should be able to tell you the technologies supported by the SIMs you are supposed to work with, for example "GlobalPlatform Amend. B support".

It is listed as a requirement for LTE UICCs in [this document](http://www.simalliance.org/en?t=/documentManager/sfdoc.file.supply&fileID=1372959014936) from the SIM Alliance.

Comment: Lets say we are supposed to provide the http applet. Is it technically feasible through SIM APIs and can be provided by a third party(SIM developer) i.e neither the SIM manufacturer or the OTA server provider?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I would not be able to estimate the project's complexity, it is not going to be a walk in the park...

Comment: After doing some research it seems that the http agent is theoretically possible, but practically of highest complexity. First it has to support specific PSK-TLS schemes, second be able to communicate BIP with the device, third convert http requests to BIP PDUs, in addition to writing the http protocol stuff.